# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView populateview

Tags: java, android, textview

How do I fix this?

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.vicevirus.myapplication, PID: 10011
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
     at com.example.vicevirus.myapplication.MainActivity$2.populateView(MainActivity.java:66)
     at com.example.vicevirus.myapplication.MainActivity$2.populateView(MainActivity.java:63)
     at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.getView(FirebaseListAdapter.java:135)
     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1616)
     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2011)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1768)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1024)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5694)
     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.vicevirus.myapplication;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.*;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.User;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editText;
    private DatabaseReference chat_data_ref;
    private DatabaseReference user_name_ref;
    private ListView listView;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String name="";
    private static final String TAG = "RegisterActivity";
    HashMap<String,String> map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        chat_data_ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat_data");
        user_name_ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat_users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("name");
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        map=new HashMap<>();
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
            }
        };
        FirebaseListAdapter<Message> adapter=new FirebaseListAdapter<Message>(
                this,Message.class,R.layout.individual_row,chat_data_ref
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, Message model, int position) {
                TextView msg=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                msg.setText(model.getUser_name()+" : "+model.getMessage());
            }
        };
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public void send(View view) {
        chat_data_ref.push().setValue(new Message(editText.getText().toString(),name));//storing actual msg with name of the user
        editText.setText("");//clear the msg in edittext
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId()==R.id.logout)
        {
            mAuth.signOut();//when the user clicks signout option this will executes
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My individual_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="top|center" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/ute"
                />
          </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_leq"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id textview1 is doubled, it is set to the linear layout and to the textview
Change one of them

Answer (score 1):

**Your id textview1 is doubled,  just remove** `android:id="@+id/textView1"` **from your linear layout**

```
 <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   <TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
```

Comment: most Welcome @NubDoto

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 views with the same id, read the logcat carefully next time

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below Line in your layout, it seems to have all issues

```
android:background="@drawable/ute"
```

Comment: Happy to help, Thanks for the heads up